# Show Items in drop tree dynamically based on Sites

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I have a requirement to show the datasource item in  droptree field and its a multi site solution. My content tree structure is as below

```
WebSite A
        Home
          
        
        Global
            Blog
                Blog Promo Card

    WebSite B
        Home
        
        Global
            Blog
                Blog Promo Card
```

My requiremet is to show items dynamically based on sites based on this template (**Blog Promo Card**). So in drop tree field on item level i should show items creted from block promo card template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a dynamic source query like this, that will match the same content tree structure for each site.

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='SITE TEMPLATE ID']//*[@@templateid='GLOBAL ITEM TEMPLATE ID']//*[@@templateid='BLOG TEMPLATE ID']
```

Also if you want to fix the path of your Content tree structure after a certain point then the query will be something like this. (In case you are using Folder to hold item)

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='SITE TEMPLATE ID']/Global/Blog/Blog Promo Card
```

Follow this article for more information

https://sitecoresandbox.com/tag/droptree/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that resolved my issue.

Comment: @AvinashSharma - accept the answer if it worked so that help quickly others.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write your dynamic source query for drop tree field like this, it will works for multisite solution and shows item based on your current site.

```
query:./ancestor::*[@@templateid='{23DA3211-A3A4-4E46-8ABD-FDE132236DCB}' or @@templateid='{23DA3211-A3A4-4E46-8ABD-FDE132236DCB}']]//*[@@name='Globals']//*[@@name='Blog']//*[@@name='Blog Promo Card']/*
```

Comment: Thank for answering this. but with this query item takes lots of time to get loaded.